# what is the most efficient way of concat two numbers to one number in python?

Tags: python

what is the most efficient way of concat two numbers to one number in python?

numbers are always in between 0 to 255, i have tested few ways by Concat as string and cast back to int but they are very costly in time vice for my code.

example

```
    a = 152 
    c = 255
    d = concat(a,c)
```

answer:

```
    d = 152255
```

Comment: @rayryeng would this not return a string?

Comment: How do you want 2 or 1 digit values of c to be treated? would `d=100*a+c` do what you want?

Comment: You don't want to concatenate numbers; you concatenate strings that *represent* numbers.

Comment: @chepner Agreed.

Comment: @rayryeng OP already mentioned that concatting a string and then converting to int is too slow for him

Comment: @N.Ivanov Missed that. Thanks. I'm curious to why it's slow though...

Comment: The requested operation raises the question of why these are numbers, and not strings, in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty fast:

```
def concat(a, b):
    return 10**int(log(b, 10)+1)*a+b
```

It uses the logarithm to find how many times the first number must be multiplied by 10 for the sum to work as a concatenation

```
In [1]: from math import log

In [2]: a = 152

In [3]: b = 255


In [4]: def concat(a, b):
   ...:     return 10**int(log(b, 10)+1)*a+b
   ...:

In [5]: concat(a, b)
Out[5]: 152255

In [6]: %timeit concat(a, b)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.18 us per loop
```

Comment: You can make it a bit faster replacing `log(b, 10)` with the approximation `b.bit_length()*0.30103`

Comment: You need to be careful with the floating point precision of the `log` function here. For example, with `b = 1000`, `log(b, 10)` is `2.9999999999999996` rather than `3` which produces the incorrect concatenation. A possible fix here is to check if `a * b >= a * 10**int(log(b, 10)+1)`, and if this is true, the answer should be `10**int(log(b, 10) + 2)*a + b`

Answer (score 5):

If the numbers are bounded, just multiply and add:

```
>>> a = 152
>>> c = 255
>>> d = a*1000+c
>>> d
152255
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there you go:

```
a = 152
b = 255

def concat(a, b):
    n = next(x for x in range(10) if 10**x>a)  # concatenates numbers up to 10**10
    return a * 10**n + b

print(concat(a, b))  # -> 152255
```

Comment: you can generalize that with a `next` and make it quite pretty.

Comment: Holy crap. You weren't kidding!

Comment: this doesn't work for some numbers, like `concat(20,50)`